# How do you trigger interrupts for an MSP430?

Tags: msp430

I could use some help with programming an MSP430. It's for a class assignment. I need to generate a sine wave, and I'm trying to do so by using the TimerA to change an output every 1/50th of the period. Im using the following setup:

```
int main(void) {
WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
TACCTL0 = CCIE;
TACTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_1 + ID_3 + TAIE; //CLK(1MHz) /8
TACCR0 = 25; //25-100 Hz 250-10Hz

P1DIR   = 0x00;
P2DIR   = 0xFF; //DAC Ouptut
P3DIR   = 0x00; //ADC Input
P4DIR   = 0x00; //Digital Input
P3SEL  |= BIT6 + BIT7;

ADC10CTL0  = SREF_0 + ADC10SHT_3 + MSC + ADC10ON + ADC10IE;
ADC10CTL1  = INCH_7 + ADC10DIV_3 + CONSEQ_1;
ADC10AE0  |= 0xC0; //Turn on ADC of 3.6 and 3.7
ADC10DTC1  = 2;

double amp = 0;
double freq = 0;
unsigned int ADC[2];

for(;;)
{
    wave_sel =P4IN;

    ADC10CTL0 &= ~ENC;
    while (ADC10CTL1 & BUSY);
    ADC10SA = (unsigned int)ADC;
    ADC10CTL0 |= ENC + ADC10SC;

    freq = (double)ADC[0]/1023;
    amp  = (double)ADC[1]/1023;

    TACCR0 = 25 + (freq*225);
    dout *= amp;
    dac_write(dout);
}
}
```

and an interrupt that has the following title:

```
#pragma vector=TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A0(void)
{
```

But when I run the program, I can't get the interrupt to trigger. I can see the timer counting up in the debugger, and it resets once it hits TACCR0 like it should, but nothing in the interrupt occurs. I put a break point in, and it never hits it. Am I declaring the ISR wrong?

Comment: You could tell us which of the many different MSP430 chips you are using. It might help to look at the example code for your chip, or to use driverlib. Show the entire setup code.

Comment: Yes, sorry, its MSP430F2272. I will edit the main post to put the whole setup in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two interrupts in use: one for the capture compare on timer A0 (`CCIE`) and also the timer A overflow (`TAIE`). If you are getting stuck in the ISR_trap then that can be explained by the fact you do not have a handler for the timer A overflow interrupt.

If you do not intend to use the timer overflow then you need to change this line:

```
TACTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_1 + ID_3 + TAIE; //CLK(1MHz) /8
```

to this:

```
TACTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_1 + ID_3; //CLK(1MHz) /8
```

If you do intend to use that second interrupt for timer A overflow then you need to make sure you read the `TAIV` register each time you enter the interurpt. There are multiple sources that cause that interrupt and that register tells you which one caused it. However, it will not be cleared until you read it (see section 12.2.6.2 TAIV, Interrupt Vector Generator in the MSP430 F2xx Family User's Guide).

Comment: Ok, I see. I didn't want the overflow interrupt, I just thought I needed that bit on for the counter interrupt. I think that should probably fix my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure general interrupts are enabled. To enable them, set `GIE` bit of the status register.

A common idiom is to enable a low power mode together with interrupts at the end of the initialization code. For that, put this line after `TACCR0 = 25`:

```
 _BIS_SR(LPM0_bits + GIE);
```

Comment: That suggestion did help, but I think I still am doing something wrong. The GIE bit of SR deactivates after going into the ISR once, and then I get stuck in something called "ISR_trap" which makes me think I wrote something wrong. The reference material in my class doesn't mention having to do anything special inside the ISR besides the action you want done, but am I supposed to reset GIE everytime I use the interrupt?

Comment: The SR bits get restored after the interrupt. ISR_trap is for interrupts that are raised but for which you did not write a handler function.

Comment: I don't really understand. I know for a fact that I wrote an interrupt, because it runs once before I go into the trap. Do I need another function besides the __interrupt thing?

Comment: Are you, just by chance, using any other module (except the timer) that might raise an interrupt?

Comment: Ok, I figured out what was wrong, I needed to write another interrupt for TimerA1. But now that I put that in, that interrupt never terminates. its just:

    #pragma vector=TIMER0_A1_VECTOR
    __interrupt void Timer_A1(void)
    {}

But its stuck like that

Comment: @Zephyr If you don't read the `TAIV` in the handler, the interrupt flag is not cleared, and the interrupt is continuously retriggered. But you really don't need to enable both `TAIE` and `CCIE`; see @tinman's answer.